# preventDefault does not seem to be working with Firefox for an <a> tag with child elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firefox, preventdefault

I have the following use case for a customer: Assuming that there exists a parent <a> tag with a href and child elements. The link in the tag will only be called conditionally when one of the child elements has been clicked (otherwise the call should be prevented via javascript). But here I have observed a problem with the preventDefault, which does not seem to prevent the opening of the link within the Firefox browser. Does anyone has been confrontend with a similar problem and has found a workaround for the Firefox browser?

There seems to be a problem with the event propagation between the child elements and the <a> tag. I am using jQuery as a framework.

The following code snippet illustrates that problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.container a').click(function (e) {
    console.log('a tag clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.container a label').click(function(e) {
    console.log('a label clicked');
    $(this).siblings('input[type=checkbox]').trigger('click');
  });

 $('.container a input').click(function(e) {
  console.log('input clicked');
  e.stopPropagation();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a href="http://www.google.fr">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>
      <span>Click me</span>
    </label>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is a link to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wa9debfs/2/) where the redirection can be observed better.

Comment: May you add some console logs in the example?

Comment: It is invalid HTML to have an interactive element like a checkbox or `label` inside an anchor element (`a`).

Comment: input and label are part of link a, and if you put console.log in each function, you will see the sequence of events. and if you add some text before input, and click on that then your functions works as you trying,   btw the html is also wrong, checkbox is never a redirection thing

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As @HereticMonkey mentioned it seems that firefox is acting differently for event propagation of invalid placement of interactive elements within a tag.

Comment: As others have mentioned, the order in which events are getting called matters. Based on your console.log statements, the input and label clicks are getting called before anchor tag click. So, when you call e.stopPropogation() method inside input tag click, it prevents the event from bubbling to its parent which is the anchor tag. So, e.preventDefault() does not get called. This is my understanding. Open to suggestions/corrections